# Data from django form is not being posted in Postgressql Database despite getting 200 OK from the server

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms

I am using Django version 3.0 to create a sign up application for various departments at my school. I have connected the form to a model and the model is stored in a postgressql database. After I start the server using python manage.py runserver and I complete the form and click save, the form refreshes and I get the OK HTTP Code 200 from the server accessed through the terminal, but when I query the postgressql database using pg Admin interface the data has not been stored. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? This process worked before, I'm not sure if the data is just being stored in another table. Please help out if you can.

This is my base.html file:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Signup Prototype</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
        <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function(){
            $("#id_date").datepicker();
          });
        </script>

        {{form.media}}

    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="page-header">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="{% url 'Engineering' %}" class="top-menu">
                </a>
                <h1><a href="/">Signup </a></h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my engineering.html file that displays the form

```
<html> 
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
   <h2>Engineering</h2>
   <form method="POST" class="engineering-form">{% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
       <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
   </form>
{% endblock %}
<html>
```

This is my .views file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import Engineering

def engineering(request):
    form = Engineering()
    return render(request, 'my_app/engineering.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my form

```
class Engineering(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name")
    etoken_user = forms.BooleanField(required = False, label="Etoken Use")
    mfa_use = forms.BooleanField(required = False, label="MFA Use")
    usage_type = forms.CharField(label="Usage Type")
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
    user_id = forms.CharField(label="USERid")
    date = forms.DateTimeField(label="Date") # date just time stamp the date they are using

    class Meta: #tells django which model should be used to create the form
        model = Engineering
        fields = ('name','etoken_user', 'mfa_use','usage_type','email','user_id','date')
        widgets = {
        'datetime':DateTimeWidget(attrs={'id':'UTC' },usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=4)
        }
```

this is the model

```
class Engineering(models.Model):
    user_name     = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    etoken_use    = models.BooleanField()
    mfa_use       = models.BooleanField()
    usage_type    = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    date_recorded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    email         = models.EmailField(max_length = 150)
    user_id       = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the earlier answer noted, you are not doing anything with the data posted from the forms in the view.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import Engineering

def engineering(request):
    form = Engineering()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Engineering(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # probably a redirect over here.
    return render(request, 'my_app/engineering.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this matches what the documentation says to do. I will try using the solution you posted though, thank you.

Comment: if that helped you can mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes, because your view does not do anything with the data on POST.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: Thanks! the documentation really helped.